# Parse dates from an HTML table in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to use HighCharts' HTML-table-to-chart script to create a line graph from a table.

I want to have a `datetime` x-axis, so here is what I have done:

- Use `Date.parse(this.innerHTML)` to convert row headers into date strings.
- Set `type` to `datetime` in my xAxis options object.

The date conversion is working and appears correctly in the default tooltip, but the graph itself is treating the x values like categories, not datetimes. I'm assuming it has to do with how the point objects are set up, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
Highcharts.visualize = function(table, options) {

    // the categories
    options.xAxis.categories = [];

    $('tbody th', table).each(function(i) {
        var date = Date.parse(this.innerHTML);
        options.xAxis.categories.push(date);
    });

    // the data series
    options.series = [];
    $('tr', table).each(function(i) {
        var tr = this;
        $('th, td', tr).each(function(j) {
            if (j > 0) { // skip first column
                if (i === 0) { // get the name and init the series
                    options.series[j - 1] = {
                        name: this.innerHTML,
                        data: []
                    };
                } else { // add values
                    options.series[j - 1].data.push(parseFloat(this.innerHTML));
                }
            }
        });
    });

    charts[charts.length] = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
};
```

Any suggestions?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/et2Vy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts treats the xAxis as categories because you tell it to do so.
Here: `options.xAxis.categories.push(date);`

You'll have to use `{ x: xval, y: yval }` (or `[xval,yval]`) as data type for your series.

Comment: I suspected it would have to be done this way—so, basically, there's no way to do this without rewriting the parser.

Answer (score 1):

You may have set the xAxis to datetime but your are setting the category list (`options.xAxis.categories = [];`). What you need to do is send in the x,y value as one "point" into your data.push.

Answer (score 0):

dateTimeLabelFormats : Object
For a datetime axis, the scale will automatically adjust to the appropriate unit. This member gives the default string representations used for each unit. For an overview of the replacement codes, see dateFormat. Defaults to:
{
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M',
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y'
}
[example on highcharts reference](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/)

any way this might not the correct answer , hope this helps :)

Comment: got it from highcharts reference , under Axis ,